# Printing out a list of factorials from (0 to n) in C

Tags: c, loops, factorial

So I'm just starting to learn to code and maybe it's because I don't fully understand the nature of loops.

So what I want the output to be is:

If the inputted value is 6 for example, the program should produce this:

- 0! = 1
- 1! = 1
- 2! = 2
- 3! = 6
- 4! = 24
- 5! = 120
- 6! = 720

But instead it is printing this:

- 0! = 1
- 6! = 720

Without the bullet points obviously. Clearly that second for loop is not printing out properly. I'm not sure as to why. If someone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I really should have specified what I'm looking for. Thank you for all the helpful responses. I realize that all your solutions may be valid but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve creating new procedures and functions. **For my assignment using additional functions/procedures other than main() is not valid.** The problem in my code appears to be that that second for loop is not being run through at all and I have no idea why. The program should take an input value normally but I hardcoded the values into the variables thinking that would make a difference but it isn't. If there's any way to achieve this using just if, for, or while loops would be the optimal way for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

   int main( void )
{
    int number1 = 4;
    int number2;
    int factorial = 1;
    int factorialPrev = 1;

    printf("0! = 1\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < number1; i++)
    {
        factorial = factorial * (number1 - i);
    }

    for (int i = number1 - 1; i <= 0; i--)
    {
        number2 = number1 - i;
        factorialPrev = factorialPrev * number2;
        printf("%d! = %d\n", number2, factorialPrev);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you think that `for (c = number - 1; c == 0; c--)` might have something to do with it?  When number is `1`, it will print.  And then there's a `printf()` afterwards that prints the rest.  Do you need `c >= 0`?  Incidentally, 12! does fit into a 32-bit integer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's what I was thinking but I can't seem to wrap my head around this. :P

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: the loop structure is peculiar, shall we say.  The first loop calculates the factorial starting to multiply with `number` (rather than `1`).  The second loop then attempts to recalculate the values which should be generated if you started with `1` instead of `number`.  It would seem better to me to use one loop to calculate and print the values in increasing order.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a little... confusing, so I'll just rewrite it. Here's the absolute minimum functionality:

```
printf("0! = 1\n");

int factorial = 1;
for (int n = 1; n <= number; n++) {
    factorial *= n;
    printf("%d! = %d\n", n, factorial);
}
```

Let's wrap this inside a function:

```
void printFactorials(int number) {
    printf("0! = 1\n");

    int factorial = 1;
    for (int n = 1; n <= number; n++) {
        factorial *= n;
        printf("%d! = %d\n", n, factorial);
    }
}
```

And now let's add some guards for invalid inputs:

```
void printFactorials(int number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        printf("Input cannot be less than 0");
        return;
    }

    if (number > 9) {
        printf("Input cannot be greater than 9");
        return;
    }

    printf("0! = 1\n");

    int factorial = 1;
    for (int n = 1; n <= number; n++) {
        factorial *= n;
        printf("%d! = %d\n", n, factorial);
    }
}
```

Finally, let's use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter a positive integer between 0 and 9: ");

    int number;
    if (scanf("%d", &number) == 1)
        printFactorials(number);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This should be a right answer :**

```
void showfacto(int max) {
if (max< 0) {
    printf("the max cannot be less than 0");
    return;
}   
printf("0! = 1\n");
int x=1;
for (int i= 1; n <= number; n++) {
 {   for(int j=1;j<i)
      x=x*j;
    }
    printf("%d! = %d\n",i, x);
 }
```

if you want to limit the max number , you only need to add a condition if the number is greater than 9 for exemple , return.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this with repeated calls to a recursive function, just to get the factorial of a single number. Something like this:

```
int fact(int num) {
    if(num > 1) {
        return num * fact(num - 1);
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So an initial call to fact(5) would go all the way to fact(1) which returns 1. Then control goes back to fact(2) where you have 2 * the number returned from fact(1), which is 1. And so on from there until it gets back to the initial call of fact(5) which should return the final value.

```
fact(1) = 1
fact(2) = 2 * 1  = 2
fact(3) = 3 * 2  = 6
fact(4) = 4 * 6  = 24
fact(5) = 5 * 24 = 120
```

Then in main() you'd have a loop that calls the recursive function from num to 0, decrementing. Or if you want you can start from 0 and increment up to num.

```
for(x = num; x >= 0; --x) {
    factNum = fact(x);
    printf("%d! = %d\n", x, factNum);
}
```

Comment: So I should clarify that we haven't started using procedures in our course yet and are not allowed to use concepts past what we have learned. Thus everything must be defined in the main function. Thank you for all your answers but our course so far has only went as far as introducing loops. I don't think these solutions will be valid for my assignment.

Comment: You just have have to put the contents of Ulhaq's printFactorials() inside main().